# Switching the order of block elements with CSS

Tags: html, css

## Short Story

Let's say my HTML is already set in stone:

```
<div id="blockA">Block A</div>
<div id="blockB">Block B</div>
<div id="blockC">Block C</div>
```

It will look like this:

```
------------
| Block A  |
------------
| Block B  |
------------
| Block C  |
------------
```

Now I want to switch the order of the blocks. How can I do that with only *CSS*?

```
------------
| Block C  |
------------
| Block A  |
------------
| Block B  |
------------
```

I'm aware there's hacky solutions such as using `position:absolute`, but this doesn't preserve the effective use of the `display:block` property. That is, blocks push other blocks downward when they grow in size.

## Long Story

When user uses a computer to view my webpage, the blocks are displayed in this order:

1. General info.
2. Event schedule.
3. iPhone app advertisement

The iPhone app advertisement is placed last because it's not terribly important to computer users. A small percentage of computer users will whip out their phone and install the app.

If a mobile user comes to this site, the iPhone app advertisement should be the most important thing on the page. Therefore, it should be moved to the top:

1. iPhone app advertisement
2. General info.
3. Event schedule.

I would like iPhone and computer users to share the same HTML, but have a CSS media query switch the order of the blocks.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   #blockC {
      /* magic order switching */
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this with *only* CSS, if you mind me asking?

Comment: `position: absolute` doesn't change `display: block`.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this in CSS and not JavaScript?  Are you worried about users with JavaScript turned off?

Comment: `position:absolute` doesn't preserve the stacking and pushing nature of `display:block`, which is the whole point of having a block element.

Comment: It's not possible through efficient CSS, though some jQuery could do the magic, I could show you if you want.

Comment: I just like to have distinct roles for HTML, CSS, and JS. I like HTML to only deal with **information**, CSS to only deal with **appearance**, and JS to only deal with user **interaction**. I'm OCD about model-view-controller. If I have to change my HTML to change the appearance, then a little piece of my heart dies.

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable to want to do this through CSS - I would rather put it behind a media query and let that be the single source of truth for how the site's layout will respond than splitting that logic across css and js.

Comment: Anyone who wants to achieve similar effect with Bootstrap3 columns, [here is one tutorial](https://web3canvas.com/re-order-columns-in-mobile-devices-using-bootstrap-3/).

Comment: If you just use css, you can use flex: 

`div {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
flex-direction: row-reverse; //revert horizontally
//flex-direction: column-reverse; revert vertically
}`

Comment: Bruh your short story is a long as your long story XD

Answer (score 122, accepted):

As has already been suggested, [Flexbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) is the answer - particularly because you only need [to support](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) a single modern browser: Mobile Safari.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/hLUHL/

You can remove the `-moz-` prefixed properties if you like, I just left them in for future readers.

```css
    #blockContainer {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: box;
        
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -moz-box-orient: vertical;
        box-orient: vertical;
    }
    #blockA {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
        -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
        box-ordinal-group: 2;
    }
    #blockB {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
        -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
        box-ordinal-group: 3;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="blockContainer">
        <div id="blockA">Block A</div>
        <div id="blockB">Block B</div>
        <div id="blockC">Block C</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Let's just hope Windows 7 phone with its freaking IE never becomes mainstream so we can continue using cool CSS like this.

Comment: Brilliant but could be very slow on complex pages

Comment: The flexbox specification changed, see here for examples of the new implementation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes

Comment: For this solution, you would have to hope that the underlying implementation uses IDs or some other mechanism to unique identify each div inside the blockContainer.

Comment: @Doug how about using `nth-child` to target the elements?

Comment: I just added the `-ms-` prefix to get it to work on mobile IE.

Comment: Hm, it uses the `display` property that's probably sometimes cannot be modified. For example, is it possible to exchange two cells in a table?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv: [This might help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414478/make-a-div-display-under-another-using-css-in-a-totally-fluid-layout/10415503#10415503)

Comment: @thirtydot yep. I really think that the concept of orderable boxes is amazing, but I thought it could be implemented using another CSS property not breaking the "original" displays. Bad luck. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Here is a fork of this fiddle that adds support for IE10: http://jsfiddle.net/15Ljpn2q/2/

Comment: This does not work with IE 9 or older. Use display:flex and order:[number] instead it works with IE 10 and newer.

Comment: Nice. Now how would you change that so that the output will be in 1 line with the preceding and following text (like: "Blocks: Block C Block A Block B are available"). Changing the "vertical" to "horizontal" works half way. The 3 blocks are in 1 line, but they are on a line of their own, not together with the other text.

Comment: It is a okay solution but it's not working on IE11. The better and newer solution, and also works on IE11:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

Comment: I didn't see anyone refer to Jamie Wong's beautiful code that uses CSS to move elements vertically and horizontally.  Visit http://jamie-wong.com/2011/10/16/fifteen-puzzle-algorithm/ and open Dev Tools to watch the pieces of the puzzle move visually but not in their HTML positions.

Answer (score 151):

Here is a "simple as possible" example, for changing the order of div-elements (when resizing the browser window):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foobar</title>
    <style>
      @media screen and (max-width:300px){
        #parent{
          display:flex;
          flex-flow: column;
        }
        #a{order:2;}
        #c{order:1;}
        #b{order:3;}
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="parent">
      <div id="a">one</div>
      <div id="b">two</div>
      <div id="c">three</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/devnull/qyroxexv/
(change window-width to see the effect of changing the order of the divs)

Answer (score 67):

### Update: Two lightweight CSS solutions:

Using [**flex**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex), [**flex-flow**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow) and [**order**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order):

### [Example1: Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m37cxb9g/5/)

```
    body{
        display:flex;
        flex-flow: column;
    }
    #blockA{
        order:4;
    }
    #blockB{
        order:3;
    }
    #blockC{
        order:2;
    }
```

Alternatively, reverse the Y scale:

### [Example2: Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m37cxb9g/6/)

```
body{
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
div{
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
}
```

Comment: omg, example2 is fantastic)

Comment: That second example is pretty interesting. Thanks for the share!

Comment: example 2 is magic!

Comment: I can't say "wow" enough for the example 2! But I think it doesn't work for a horizontal list of items.

Comment: This works best for horizontally listed elements i.e. mobile View

Comment: Example #2 is a neat trick - but should NOT be used in production because it breaks everything from text-selection, to TTS (screen-readers for blind users), and many other things. Wow.

Answer (score 39):

I known this is old, but I found a easier solution and it works on ie10, firefox and chrome:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="one">One</div>
  <div id="two">Two</div>
  <div id="three">Three</div>
</div>
```

This is the css:

```
#wrapper {display:table;}
#one {display:table-footer-group;}
#three {display:table-header-group;}
```

And the result:

```
"Three"
"Two"
"One"
```

I found it [here](http://www.jtudsbury.com/thoughts/rearrange-div-order.php).

Comment: Very helpful for when using a table!

Answer (score 12):

This method worked for me without flexbox:

```css
#blockA,
#blockB,
#blockC {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 20px;
}


.reverseOrder,
#blockA,
#blockB,
#blockC {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
       -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
         -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="reverseOrder">
    <div id="blockA">Block A</div>
    <div id="blockB">Block B</div>
    <div id="blockC">Block C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP did not want to reverse order, but change the order: C-A-B, not C-B-A.

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div id="blockC second-order">Block C</div>
<div id="blockA">Block A</div>
<div id="blockB">Block B</div>
<div id="blockC first-order">Block C</div>
```

CSS

```
.second-order {
     display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
     .first-order: {
         display: none;
     }

     .second-order: {
         display: block;
     }
}
```

I think this is non-stupid solution becouse repeating content is no problem in the most of cases and in your case if it is advertisment you would repeat not a lot of content.

I've answers on this question althought one year passed, becouse I was searching for solution, I read this and got this idea.

Comment: Interesting "thinking outside the box" approach. However, I would only recommend it if the duplicated content is inserted automatically or duplicated via some include mechanism. If it means cut/paste a block of content, that would be a maintenance nightmare. (Someone will come along later, and only make a fix in one place, test it on one screen width, and not realize they didn't fix it in all cases.)

Comment: I agreed, but I think if we use some include mechanism there shouldn't be a problem with coping/pasting, but without it my solution is not the best - I know.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="a">Block A</div>
    <div id="b">Block B</div>
    <div id="c">Block C</div>
</div>
```

lets say the height of a block is 100px

```
#container     {position:relative; height: 300px;}
#a, #b, #c     {position:absolute; height: 100px}
#c             {top: 0px;}
#b             {top: 100px;}
#a             {top: 200px;}
```

Comment: I don't want to hardcode the heights. The elements inside are dynamic, so the height is not known.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it with CSS `display: table-*`. I haven't tested with more than 3 blocks though.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yodapt/g9f9w/)

Comment: Good to see a solution that doesn't require CSS3 flex. Not generalizable to more than 3 top-level boxes -- but often that is enough.

Answer (score 1):

You could mess with the margins: http://jsfiddle.net/zV2p4/

But you would probably be better off using `position: absolute`. This does not change `display: block`, but it will make the width auto. To fix this, make the divs `width: 100%`

Comment: What if I wanted to preserve the block property? That is, if the top block all of a sudden has more text added, the bottom blocks would be pushed downward. With your hardcoding of margins, the blocks would collide.

Comment: You should probably use JavaScript then. There may be a CSS3 property that will accomplish this. But, CSS3 is not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Possible in CSS3: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-writing-modes/#writing-mode

Why not change the orders of the tags? Your HTML page isn't made out of stone, are they?

Comment: Layout flow is deprecated... Use writing mode instead

Comment: @Will - Thanks, I was looking at the wrong resource.

Answer (score 0):

Hows this for low tech...

put the ad at the top and bottom and use media queries to display:none as appropriate.

If the ad wasn't too big, it wouldn't add too much size to the download, you could even customise where the ad sent you for iPhone/pc.

Comment: BTW, this is what @kspacja's answer does, and it has code details.