# CSS/Responsive/Mobile: Left/Right Sidebar after the Content though first in HTML?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

Hi there I wonder if there is a NICE solution for solving the following problem:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left_sidebar">blablabla</div>
<div id="right_sidebar">blablabla</div>
<div id="main_content">blablabla</div>
</div>
```

In the desktop version of the Website the CSS is something like:

```
#main_content {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 45%;
}

#left_sidebar {
float:left;
width:25%;
}

#right_sidebar {
float:right;
width:25%;
}
```

In the mobile/responsive version the aim is to let the main content first. However the **order of the HTML should NOT be changed** (I know that there are solutions for this). Is it possible with **pure CSS** (within a media query) to let the main_content appear before the left_sidebar/right_sidebar in the mobile version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally I found another topic on stackoverflow dealing with the same problem. The solution provided there should be exactly what is needed.

[Switching the order of block elements with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425665/switching-the-order-of-block-elements-with-css)