# Use CSS flexbox to move radio below label

Tags: html, css

I can't modify the output of this html but I can use CSS to move the items around. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7430355/3557005) and know that I can move the elements around using that but I want the bullets to move below the words and center both.
I'm trying get it to look like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/odmxkqy2/) using the html in this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/jkrfnxLd/).
This is what I have so far

```
#edit-submitted-recommendation {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    box-orient: horizontal;
}
.form-radio {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    box-ordinal-group: 2;
}
.option {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    box-ordinal-group: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this. It's a but off because best case would be swapping the position of the label and input in the div, but if you can only edit the css this works

```
div.form-item{
    display:inline-block;
}
div.form-item input{
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
div.form-item label{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Make your `.form-items` inline flexboxes and set the `flex-flow` to `column`.
- Use `order` to put the labels on top.
- Center your labels and inputs.

This gets the labels on top of the buttons and centers them. Make it look a bit nicer by surrounding the options with some whitespace. [It should now look like somewhat like this.](http://jsfiddle.net/woestijnrog/hugrytup/)