# How to move positions of divs using css

Tags: html, css

How can I make an element visually switch position with another element using CSS? For example, if I have this HTML markup:

```
<html>
 <body>
    <div class="div1">Div1</div>
    <div class="div2">Div2</div>
    <div class="div3">Div3</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want `.div3` and `.div1` to switch places. How can I do this using **CSS**?

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using flexbox's `order` property:

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex > div {
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.div1 {order: 3;}
.div2 {order: 2;}
.div3 {order: 1;}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="div1">Div1</div>
  <div class="div2">Div2</div>
  <div class="div3">Div3</div>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image: preview]

Comment: Thanks @praveen Kumar but how to do it without using flex?

Comment: why do you want to do it without flex? Divs should be aligned in the same line?

Comment: @fcalderan i have parent div whose display property value is table and i then arranged all of its children as columns.

Comment: @UAK Flex is the only thing that allows you to change the order of elements... AFAIK.

Comment: @PraveenKumar we can do without fles, see https://jsfiddle.net/vsfcgfe6/

Comment: For reference read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425665/switching-the-order-of-block-elements-with-css)

Comment: @Leothelion FlexBox seems better than that.

Comment: I just gave this link as op wants to without flex, m not considering which one is better as for me i think the way is better by which we get our solution, isn't it :)