# Set a close icon in the top right corner of an image

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a list of images using angularjs. I would like to display a close icon image in the top right corner of the each image. Please help me with the CSS, below is the code for listing images.

```
<div ng-repeat="file in imagefinaldata" style="display:inline;">
    <img  height=200 width=250 data-ng-if="store.imageUrl !== ''" ng-src="{{store.imageUrl}}{{file}}"  class="imgResponsiveMax" alt=""/>
    <img class="close" src="http://wecision.com/enterprise/images/icons/closeIcon.png"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add class in image parent div and do CSS. See below snippet.

```css
.img_wrp {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="file in imagefinaldata" class="img_wrp">
  <img height=200 width=250 src="https://wecision.com/images/wrc-1.png" class="imgResponsiveMax" alt="" />
  <img class="close" src="http://wecision.com/enterprise/images/icons/closeIcon.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this, it should work

```css
.img-container {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
}
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container" ng-repeat="file in imagefinaldata">
  <img height=200 width=250 data-ng-if="store.imageUrl !== ''" ng-src="{{store.imageUrl}}{{file}}" class="imgResponsiveMax" alt="" />
  <img class="close" src="http://wecision.com/enterprise/images/icons/closeIcon.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the parent for the shake of this example:

```
<div ng-repeat="file in imagefinaldata" class="parent">
    <img  height=200 width=250 data-ng-if="store.imageUrl !== ''" ng-src="{{store.imageUrl}}{{file}}"  class="imgResponsiveMax" alt=""/>
    <img class="close" src="http://wecision.com/enterprise/images/icons/closeIcon.png"  />
</div>
```

And your style can me like this:

```
.parent {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto; // Or your height
}
.parent img.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 21px;
  width: 21px;
}
```

Of course alter this style to match your needs. There was no example to provide you exactly the sizes.

Answer (score 0):

please take looke at this link [Switching the order of block elements with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425665/switching-the-order-of-block-elements-with-css)

maybe its help

but you can do it with position rule in css

use this css code :

```
.imagefinaldata{position:relative;}
.imagefinaldata .close{width:21px;height:21px;position:absolute;left:3px; top:3px;}
.imagefinaldata img:first-child{margin-top:30px;}
```

I hop this help