# page layout with header section main and footer tag

Tags: html, css

I have 4 blocks Header,Section,Main,Footer.

[The layout of my site](https://www.tarsim.org)

I added a horizontal menu in the header and I set it above the section menu that has my slider. but the problem is I want to set the menu vertical when the page width is less than 1136 pixel, the menu covers my slider in section and i don't want that. what i want is the menu below the section so the user can see the menu and slider. 
i put my web site URL to understand well.

```css
/*Header Tag*/
.cd-header {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0,1,1,0.4);
}
  /*section Tag*/
.cd-hero{
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
  /*main Tag*/
.cd-main-content {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 2em 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: all you do is just minimize a little bit you browser and tell me why my slider goes behind my menu. i think the answer is to simple and i confused to find it. so instead comment me like this please answer me if you can find the problem. thanks a lot.

Comment: I refer you to my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FASTER WAY by just using display:none**

Add another menu below your **section** where the slider is, and only show it when it reaches the width `1136px`.

**Another way is using flex**

With flex you can set the order of items; here's a guide to [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). for reference as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425665/switching-the-order-of-block-elements-with-css)

Example using flex:

```
<header>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>...links...</nav>
        <div class="slider"></div>
    </div>
</header>
<section></section>

/** CSS **/
header .wrapper {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:1136px){
    nav {
        order:2;
    }
    .slider {
        order:1;
    }
}
```