# Ordering of contents inside a div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a content like this:

```
<div class="overview cellpadding" id="websitesandportals">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class="col-md-6 even">
                <img src="/assets/images/custom portal.jpg" alt="Image 2" class="img-full img-responsive servicesubpageimage" >
                <div class="empty-space sm-30 xs-30"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 servicesubpagetextcol odd">
                <div class="col-content" >
                    <h1 class=" content-title bighead text-left service-subpage-subheadings">hhghhhhhhhhh</h1>
                    <div class="simple-text text-justify service-subpage-subheadings-content">
                        <p>ghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</p>
                        <a href="contactus.html">
                              <div class="service-subpage-button">
                                    <div class="sim-button button6  stripbutton webdevelopbutton service-subpage-button-div"><span>Get Quote</span></div>
                                 </div>
                        </a>                        
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

i want to display the content first and image ath the bottom in small devices and xs devices. But in large screens.how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching the order of block elements with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425665/switching-the-order-of-block-elements-with-css). [This answer about `flex` on that question should be easy to implement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25077310/1499877)

Comment: You can use the `order` CSS helper class in Bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#order-classes

Comment: You may find https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the col size xs - xl - md, etc, in this case I use col-lg-12, to use the 12 cols of bootstrap grid

[Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="overview cellpadding" id="websitesandportals">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class = "row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 even">
    <img src="/assets/images/custom portal.jpg" alt="Image 2" class="img-full img-responsive servicesubpageimage" >
    <div class="empty-space sm-30 xs-30"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 servicesubpagetextcol odd">
    <div class="col-content" >
    <h1 class=" content-title bighead text-left service-subpage-subheadings">hhghhhhhhhhh</h1>
    <div class="simple-text text-justify service-subpage-subheadings-content">
 <p>ghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</p>
     <a href="contactus.html">
     <div class="service-subpage-button">
    <div class="sim-button button6  stripbutton webdevelopbutton service-subpage-button-div"><span>Get Quote</span></div>
    </div>
    </a>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this class `flex-sm-row flex-column-reverse` in your `<div class = "row">`

you can use `flex-sm-row` or `flex-md-row` as per your choice

also add class `img-fluid` in image tag if you want to responsive image

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="overview cellpadding" id="websitesandportals">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class = "row flex-md-row flex-column-reverse">
            <div class="col-md-6 even">
                <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/05/27/21/46/flowers-5229022_1280.jpg"  alt="Image 2" class="img-fluid servicesubpageimage" >
               
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 servicesubpagetextcol odd">
                <div class="col-content" >
                    <h1 class=" content-title bighead text-left service-subpage-subheadings">hhghhhhhhhhh</h1>
                    <div class="simple-text text-justify service-subpage-subheadings-content">
                        <p>ghhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh</p>
                        <a href="contactus.html">
                              <div class="service-subpage-button">
                                    <div class="sim-button button6  stripbutton webdevelopbutton service-subpage-button-div"><span>Get Quote</span></div>
                                 </div>
                        </a>                        
                    </div>
               </div>
          </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```