# How to swap two elements using CSS?

Tags: css

I want to show date below the blog title using css. I cannot edit its HTML.

Current order is: date, title, excrept, read more.
I want to show it as: title, date, excrept, read more.

I tried using `inline-block` but nothing happens.

```html
   <div class="exad-post-grid-body">
       <ul class="exad-post-data show-avatar-no">
          <li class="exad-post-date"><span><a href="https://mytimios.ml/goodness-of-cumin-for-children/" class="exad-post-grid-author-date">October 7, 2020</a>
             </span>
          </li>
       </ul>
       <h3><a href="https://mytimios.ml/goodness-of-cumin-for-children/" class="exad-post-grid-title">Goodness of Cumin for Children</a></h3>
       <div class="exad-post-grid-description">As we all know, cumin is one of the spices that has been used since generations, across cultures. It is...</div>
       <div class="exad-post-footer"><a href="https://mytimios.ml/goodness-of-cumin-for-children/" class="read-more">+ READ MORE</a></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to include code.

Comment: I have added the code. Please check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching the order of block elements with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425665/switching-the-order-of-block-elements-with-css)

Comment: @FilipSeman I tried doing this & it moved the date to extreme bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try converting `exad-post-grid-body` to become a Flex container and reorder its subsequent Flex child as needed using the `order` property from Flex. But you might need to readjust several properties to retain the current design after converting it to Flex

Comment: Working now. Thanks :) Here is the code I used.

.exad-post-grid-body {
        display: flex;
 flex-direction:column;
}
.exad-post-grid-body :nth-child(1) { order: 2; }
.exad-post-grid-body :nth-child(2) { order: 1; }
.exad-post-grid-body :nth-child(3) { order: 4; }
.exad-post-grid-body :nth-child(4) { order: 4; }